# How to sort columns using a value generated by an ArrayFormula in Google Sheets?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Please take a look at the following spreadsheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s19zrH4X9gE8xPC5J1ACMSiZC2RrWrLRgVqGr5Zl0CQ/edit?usp=sharing

On the left-hand side, I have an array formula that counts the frequency of the words that appear on the list to the right. What I want to do is really simple: I want to sort the left 2 columns based on the count. Greater the count, higher that row should appear.

How do I do this using this system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(D:D&{"",""}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col2) 
  where Col1 != '' 
  group by Col1 
  order by count(Col2) desc
  label count(Col2)'Count'", 1))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: what is the purpose of &'ing the blanks to turn it into two columns?

Comment: @MattKing no idea. it was OP's choice. I just moded it to sort it. it could be some residue of unknown/to us not relevant part